# Activate RDP via Remote

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-8.1

I'm in a network (VPN) with a Computer that I need RDP access to. But RDP is not activated on the remote Computer.

I do have administrative Privileges on the computer. As the computer did not join the domain the group policy does not work.

Is there any way I can remotely activate RDP services? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the network you should be able to use `PSEXEC`. See [here](http://ares.gobien.be:8080/2012/01/enable-remote-desktop-remotely-with-psexec/).

Download [PSTOOLS from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). Unzip to an easy to access location. Open a `CMD` command prompt, navigate to the `PSTOOLS` location. Execute:

```
psexec \\machinename reg add "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\terminal server" /f /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Machinename should be replaced with the computername, ideally you already have admin rights to this PC, for example you run this as the domain administrator. Otherwise you have to supply credentials using -u and -p options.

If you still can’t connect this is most likely the windows firewall.
Execute:

```
psexec \\machinename netsh firewall set service remotedesktop enable
psexec \\machinename netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable
```

Comment: This is correct. What's annoying is when file/printer sharing aren't enabled on the firewall and psexec.exe won't connect as a result. Then you are stuck.